# Adding a comment under the image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a comment below the image, but for some reason the text is all over the place.
Can anyone from the forum help me, please?

Images have margin-bottom: 4em; and I want to put a comment exactly there.

```
  <img src="/Screenshot_1.png" alt="" class="image1">
  <img src="/Screenshot_2.png" alt="" class="image2">
  <img src="/Screenshot_3.png" alt="" class="image3">
  <img src="/Screenshot_5.png" alt="" class="image4">
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add all relevant code - including css.

Comment: Do you want the text under all images or just one?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You have so many questions here on SO in the last couple of days. I suggest you start doing some research and try learning by yourself at least the basic stuff. You shouldn't use SO community to make your assignments for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **figure** tag

> The  tag specifies self-contained content, like illustrations,
> diagrams, photos, code listings, etc.
>
> While the content of the  element is related to the main flow,
> its position is independent of the main flow, and if removed it should
> not affect the flow of the document.

read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://www.mandysam.com/img/random.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
            <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you! Do you know why it might be moving my header element?

Comment: please show us your code (paste it in codepen or somewhere else)